# Bind Class to UserControl

Tags: vb.net

Is it possible to bind a declared class to a UserControl and will it keep the class as a snapshot or as a running code?

Example: I declare a class named MyClass that has a single property called strTest. I set that value as "What". I have a UserControl on the form that needs access to strTest, so I pass the class to it by declaring a Property in the UserControl Called MyClass and on the main form I send it MyClass.

```
UserControl.MyClass = MyClass
```

Now, if I update MyClass on the main form by changing strTest to equal "Where", will the class in UserControl also update to "Where" or will it still have "What"?

Edit, It takes it like a snapshot.

So, how do I data bind a class to a class inside a UserControl (or other form for that matter)?

Comment: You could test it for yourself in less time than it took to compose the question.

Comment: I just did. I was hoping someone would give a one line, no - you just do this simple statement. I'd then vote them up and mark it as the best answer.